# How are page views on user profiles or questions tabulated?

Tags: discussion, questions, views, profile-page

Is there a different means by which page views on questions and those on user profiles are tabulated? As in, can a user view their own profile or own question and that count as "1" view ? Or are page views tabulated only for unique visitors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: It's tracked by IP, so you can't just refresh and increase view counts.

Long answer: Read the Meta Stack Overflow topic here: [How does Stack Overflow calculate the number of views in a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36728/how-does-stack-overflow-calculate-the-number-of-views-in-a-question/36729#36729) – it goes into much more detail.